# Facebook like notifications DB logic for entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Can anyone please show me a guideline for the notification logic like in Facebook?

for example If I have

```
public Class Profile
{
public string UserName {get; set;}
public virtual Team TeamId {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<MessageBoard> Notify {get; set;}
}
```

Another Class that stores Notification Messages let it be MessageBoard.

```
    public Class MessageBoard
    {
    public string Notification {get; set;}
    public string NotifyType {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles {get; set;}
    public virtual Profile Sender {get; set;}
    }
```

I Need DbmodelBuilder code to establish a relation between these two entities given above.
thanks for reading. Even changes in those two classes are also welcome. Please give an Idea.